# How to make dotted line in a binary array

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, scipy.ndimage

how to create the dotted line in the below NumPy array

```
import NumPy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

x=np.array( [ [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
          [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

def make_figure(inp_arr: np.array, outputname):
    # create graphical output for visual check
    cmap = ListedColormap([ 'r','b','g'])
    plt.imshow(inp_arr, cmap=cmap)
    plt.grid(color='b', linestyle=':', linewidth=0.55)
    plt.savefig(input_folder + 'pics_' + str(outputname) + '.png', format='png', dpi=350)
    # plt.show()
    #plt.clf()
```

bh=make_figure(b,'gh')

requirement: how to convert element 1 into 0 with the step of two expected outputs is like
I tried with a brute force algorithm, but I am not able to find the solution

[image]

output array looks like

```
 y=np.array( [ [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

for visual representation like making a dotted line

[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  You want to perform some operation(s) on `x` `np.array` to transform it into `y` `np.array`?

Comment: y array is the output of x array. like access the every 2nd consecutive element values 1 in an array x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to find the minimum weight full path, then take the first point, skip two points, and repeat until the end of the path.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import radius_neighbors_graph
from scipy import sparse
import networkx as nx
x = np.array( [ [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] ] )

x_nonzeros = x.nonzero()
num_points = len(x_nonzeros[0])

x_coords = [[x_nonzeros[0][k], x_nonzeros[1][k]] for k in range(num_points)]

neighbors = radius_neighbors_graph(x_coords, radius=1.5, mode="distance")

G = nx.Graph(neighbors)

full_paths = [
  {"path": path, "weight": nx.classes.path_weight(G, path, weight="weight")}
  for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, 0, 40) if len(path)==num_points
]

full_paths.sort(key=lambda rec: rec["weight"])

the_path = full_paths[0]["path"]

y_coords = [x_coords[coord] for coord in the_path[0::3]]

y = sparse.coo_array(([1]*len(y_coords),np.array(y_coords).T)).toarray()

print(y)
# [[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0]]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, 
Is any way to select an automatic target path points

Comment: like endpoint we can select using np.count_nonzero(x)-1, is it possible to access non continues different paths

Comment: @raja I'm not sure - I'm a graph theory noob.  `nx.all_simple_paths(G, 0, 40)` is using the identifiers of the `start` and `target` nodes of the graph `G`. If we know the starting node `0`, we can get the farthest node like this: `farthest_node = reduce(lambda x,y: y if y[1]>x[1] else x, nx.single_source_shortest_path_length(G, 0).items())[0]`.